# Can I change the arrow icon of choicebox in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to change choicebox arrow icon because default icon is not suitable for my application. I didn't find any documentation about changing icon using css.

I tried to write css properities like this but it didn't succeeded:

```
.choice-box .arrow {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}

.choice-box .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-image: url("../icons/arrow_down_white.png");
    -fx-background-size: 32 32;
}
```

Comment: In your JavaFX distribution in the controls jar, you will find a file named `modena.css`.  It has the default CSS for all controls, including the choice-box and its arrow.  Study that code, then create your own implementation to customize the visuals.  If a recall (could be wrong), the arrows are svg paths, so you could provide your own custom svg path.  Other customizations are possible (e.g. a custom skin), but I'd recommend trying to customize the CSS first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by using -fx-shape properity and svg path like this:

```
.choice-box .open-button  .arrow {
    -fx-shape: "m1 135.469c.76-.548 1.57-.242 1.996-1.37 8.436-22.314 31.196-27.84 50.124-19.916 3.594 1.504 6.861 4.22 9.79 7.152 63.435 63.528 126.957 126.97 190.324 190.566 3.176 3.187 4.59 2.926 7.589-.082 63.153-63.34 126.583-126.403 189.57-189.906 18.037-18.184 52.119-13.714 60.844 12.708.132.402.74.647 1.444.672.319 7.395.319 15.082.319 23.238-1.567-.309-1.669.7-2.042 1.89-1.381 4.404-3.943 8.085-7.206 11.346-73.869 73.845-147.798 147.63-221.505 221.636-12.623 12.674-37.881 12.698-50.676-.163-69.553-69.915-139.393-139.543-209.104-209.3-7.658-7.664-16.25-14.586-21.079-24.937C1 151.313 1 143.625 1 135.47z";
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-pref-width: 8;
    -fx-pref-height: 4;
}
```

Special thanks to @jewelsea for providing me default javafx css style file.